# Azure Data Factory Dataflow with Azure Synapse Link to Remove Duplicate Records

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, dataverse

I am using Azure Synapse Link to connect Azure storage to load the RAW to from CRM. there is option which i choose **Append mode only**. it is creating a duplicate records if anything changes happen from CRM tables(modules). in that case, how do we handle this scenario, either aggerating in dataflow to remove the duplicate records or else we can handle in dataverse(power apps) itself. kindly advise.
eg :

```
accountnumber    accountname
222               XXX
222               XXX
222               XXX
```

how do we handle in dataverse side or else dataflow aggregation flows. kindly help me.

links referred : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-advanced-configuration

also i could find in ms docs for below snippet code but where and how do we use, if some please share the screenshot below code.

```
aggregate(groupBy(mycols = sha2(256,columns())),
    each(match(true()), $$ = first($$))) ~> DistinctRows
```

as per below link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#distinct-row-using-all-columns

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to repro this in my azure ADF dataflow environment.

- Sample source is taken as in below image.
  [image]
- Select the Aggregate transform next to source.

[image]

- In Aggregate Settings, Click **group by**  and then click **Open expression builder**
  [image]
- Enter the Column name and enter the expression as `sha2(256,columns())` and then click **Save and Finish**
  [image]
- Then, in aggregate settings, click on the aggregates and then click the **Open expression builder**
  [image]
- Click on **+ Add column pattern** near column1 and then delete Column1. Then Enter **true()** in matching condition. Then click on undefined column expression and enter `$$` in **column name expression** and `first($$)` in **value expression**. Then click **Save and Finish**.
  [image: gif11]

**Output Of Aggregate Transform**
[image]

This can be done by writing a script in dataflow. To write a dataflow transformation script , Click the script button
[image]

The script for equivalent UI transformation is shown in below image.

[image]

By this way, you can aggregate in dataflow and remove the duplicates.